# Java 8 Stream: average and count at once

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `DoubleStream` which has been calculated from a very time consuming function, and I want to calculate the Average and Count of its elements at the same time.

The Problem is I do not want to calculate the `DoubleStream` twice because of the mentioned time consuming calculation of values. I want to get the value of both Average and Count from one lambda expression.

I have tried everything with `collect` and `map` and so on but had no success.

```
    final long count = products.stream()
            .mapToDouble(this::timeConsumingCalculateRating)
            .filter(rating -> rating > 0.0D)
            .count();

    final double averageRating = products.stream()
            .mapToDouble(this::timeConsumingCalculateRating)
            .filter(rating -> rating > 0.0D)
            .average()
            .orElse(0.0D);
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#summaryStatistics()):

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = products.stream()
            .mapToDouble(this::timeConsumingCalculateRating)
            .filter(rating -> rating > 0.0D)
            .summaryStatistics();
long count = stats.getCount();
double averageRating = stats.getAverage();
```

Answer (score 5):

For count and average, `summaryStatistics` is all you need. But if you have some other terminal operation and you also need to count the elements, you could use `peek` with an `AtomicLong` or `AtomicInteger`:

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
double average = products.stream()
        .mapToDouble(this::timeConsumingCalculateRating)
        .filter(rating -> rating > 0.0D)
        .peek(d -> counter.incrementAndGet())
        .average().orElse(0.0);
long count = counter.get();
```

Comment: That `peek` should have been called `tee` ;)